# what is the meaning of the following command?

Tags: bash, unix

I need an explanation of the syntax of the following commmand:

```
 while read -u3 -r f1
```

why the -u , why the -r ? and I know that 3 is a file descriptor or identifier right ?

Comment: This is easily answered by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

From `info "(bash)Bash Builtins"` ([web mirror](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html)):

```
read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name …]

Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields.

Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD
if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as with word
splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
delimiters.

If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY variable.

     Options:
          [...]

          -r     
                Raw mode: a `\' at the end of a line does not signify line continuation and backslashes in the line don't quote the following character and are not removed.

          [...]

          -u fd

                 Read input from file descriptor fd.
```

To summarize, your command reads from file descriptor 3, ignoring backslashes for line continuation and escapes. For each of the lines, the content of the line is placed in `$f1` and one iteration of the while loop is called.

Comment: `help read` in bash shows `-u fd  read from file descriptor FD instead of the standard input`.

Comment: I started out with the zsh manpages since I'm using that myself but corrected the answer to the bash info pages.

Answer (score 2):

It reads from file descriptor 3 without treating backslashes in input as escape characters.  Every line that is read is assigned the name `f1`.

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read):

> `-r`
>
> If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character. The backslash is considered to be part of the line. In
>   particular, a backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line
>   continuation.
>
> `-u fd`
>
> Read input from file descriptor *fd*.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `read` is a shell built-in (try `type read`). That's why you won't find it as a single manual pages.

But, as a `bash` built-in, you can find its documentation in the `bash` `manpage` (or through `help read`, `help` being another `bash` built-in). Thus, quoting the adequate part of the manpage, here it is:

```
read  [-ers]  [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars] 
      [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]

    One line is read from the standard input, or from the file descriptor fd
    supplied as an  argument to the -u option, and the first word is assigned
    to the first name,  the second word  to the second name,  and so on, with
    leftover words and their intervening separators assigned to the last name.
    If there  are fewer  words read  from the input  stream  than names,  the 
    remaining names are assigned empty values.
    The characters in IFS are used to split the line into words. The backslash
    character (\) may be  used  to remove any  special  meaning  for  the next 
    character read and for line continuation.  Options,  if supplied, have the
    following meanings:
        -a aname
             The words are assigned to sequential indices of the array variable
             aname, starting at 0. aname is unset before any new values are
             assigned. Other name arguments are ignored.
        -d delim
             The first character of delim is used to terminate the input line,
             rather than newline.
        -e   If the standard input is coming from a terminal, readline (see
             READLINE above) is used to obtain the line. Readline uses the
             current (or default, if line editing was not previously active)  
             editing settings.
        -i text
             If readline is being used to read the line, text is placed into 
             the editing buffer before editing begins.
        -n nchars
             read returns after reading nchars characters rather than waiting
             for a complete line of input, but honor a delimiter if fewer than
             nchars characters are read before the delimiter.
        -N nchars
             read returns  after reading exactly nchars characters rather than
             waiting for a complete line of input, unless EOF is encountered
             or read times out. Delimiter  characters  encountered  in the
             input  are  not treated specially and do not cause read to return
             until nchars characters
                 are read.
        -p prompt
             Display prompt on standard error, without a trailing newline,
             before attempting to read any input. The prompt is displayed only
             if input is coming from a terminal.
        -r   Backslash  does not act as an escape character. The backslash is
             considered to be part of the line. In particular, a 
             backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line continuation.
        -s   Silent mode. If input is coming from a terminal, characters are 
             not echoed.
        -t timeout
             Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of 
             input is not read within time‐out seconds. timeout may be a 
             decimal number with a fractional portion following the decimal
             point. This option is only effective if read is reading input from
             a terminal, pipe, or other special file; it has no effect when
             reading from regular files.  If timeout is 0, read returns success
             if input is available on the specified file descriptor, failure
             otherwise. The  exit status is greater than 128 if the timeout is
             exceeded.
        -u fd  Read input from file descriptor fd.

    If  no names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable REPLY.
    The return code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out 
    (in which case the return code is greater than 128), or an invalid file 
    descriptor is supplied as the argument to -u.
```

In you case, lets first take a look at the options and the argument of `read -u3 -r f1`:

- `-u3` : Read input from file descriptor `3` (remember that `0` is `stdin`, `1` is `stdout` and `2` is `stderr`. `3` is not something special, just a file).
- `-r` : Backslash  does not act as an escape character.
- `f1`: Is the destination variable of the line read from `fd 3`.

So, it means that you are looping around the read as long as you can extract a line from `fd 3`, ignoring the backslashes and copying the current line in `f1`.

Comment: (Pedantic comment) `f1` will only be an environment variable if exported, otherwise it's just a variable.

Comment: Not so pedantic... I fixed this in my explanation.